# ¿Cómo equilibrar los parentesis?

Tags: java, pilas

Estoy trabajando con PILAS en java. Al momento de ingresar más paréntesis de tipo ")" me devuelve el valor `true`, cuando no quiero que haga eso, ya que si le pongo "())" no estará equilibrado pero el programa indicará que sí. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class Proceso {
    private String Cadena;
    private Stack <Character> letras = new Stack<Character>();
    public Proceso (String Cadena){
        this.Cadena=Cadena;
    }
    public boolean Proceso(){
        char Letras[]=Cadena.toCharArray();
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<Letras.length; i++){
            if (Letras[i]=='('){
                letras.push('(');
            }
            if (Letras[i]==')'){
                if (!letras.empty()){
                    letras.pop();
                }
            }
        }
        return letras.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes radica en que el último parentesis que cierra (es decir el que sobra) nunca lo ingresas a la `pila` por lo tanto cuando haces el `return` este siempre es `true` por que la `pila` esta vacia (porque ingresas el que abre y sacas el que cierra) pero no ingresas el otro que cierra.

Lo que debes hacer en el tercer caracter es validar que la `pila` no este vacia y que si no esta vacia el elemento del `head` sea diferente a un parentesis que cierra y hay si haces el `pop`, pero si esto no se cumple debes adicionar el elemento a la `pila` haciendo el `push` correspondiente.

Dejo el código modificado, tambien hice algunos cambios de nombres de variables y métodos para que fueran más standar.

```
public class Proceso {
  private String cadena;
  private Stack<Character> stackLetras = new Stack<Character>();
  public Proceso(String cadena) {
    this.cadena = cadena;
  }
  public boolean procesarCadena() {
    char arrayDeLetras[] = cadena.toCharArray();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arrayDeLetras.length; i++) {
      if (arrayDeLetras[i] == '(') {
        stackLetras.push(arrayDeLetras[i]);
      }else if (arrayDeLetras[i] == ')') {
        if (!stackLetras.empty() && stackLetras.peek() != ')') {
          stackLetras.pop();
        }else{
          stackLetras.push(arrayDeLetras[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  return stackLetras.empty();
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu propuesta, logré solucionar el error al final pero se aprecia la ayuda brindada, recalcando que también aunque de diferente forma lograste solucionar el error que tenía :D

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que podrías mantener un contador de diferencia de paréntesis (o en su defecto, de cada '*(*' y '*)*' ), además de agregar esta nueva condición en el retorno de una manera similar a:

```
return letras.empty() && (diffParentesis==0)
```

Con esto solucionará el problema expuesto, asumiendo que *diffParentesis* es el contador mencionado.